# Cordova Build error

Tags: cordova, build

I have 64 bit windows operating system installed on my LAPTOP I have installed NPM Ant Build and cordova properly. When I creates new projects and build it with command prompt it gives build successfully but as soon as I add some JS or CSS file into the folder and rebuilds gives error as 
Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: E:\Projects\Android\demo\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command fai
led with exit code 8

Comment: Are there some other errors around for instance failing to find certain files? At the beginning cordova/ionic showed me the same error despite the fact that the error had nothing to do with the environment.

Comment: I have installed new Android Studio and updated all components and It worked fine for me.